# Erlang: starting sellaprime app with supervisor returns undef error

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

Trying to run the example app, sellaprime app, from the programming erlang book. I tested the supervisor code with the testing function within the supervisor. So, the supervisor should be OK. The application gets loaded but the application start runs into problem with below error:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2021::22:39:44.235167 ===
application: sellaprime
exited: {bad_return,
            {{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]]},
             {'EXIT',
                 {undef,
                     [{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]],[]},
                      {application_master,start_supervisor,3,
                          [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,331}]},
                      {application_master,start_the_app,5,
                          [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,313}]},
                      {application_master,start_it_new,7,
                          [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                           {line,299}]}]}}}}
type: temporary
```

Need help locating the error.
Here is the file, `sellaprime_app.erl`:

```
-module(sellaprime_app).
-behaviour(application).
-export([start/2, stop/1]).

start(_Type, StartArgs) -> sellaprime_supervisor:start_link(StartArgs).
stop(_State) -> ok.
```

and the `sellaprime_supervisor.erl`:

```
-module(sellaprime_supervisor).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start/0, start_in_shell_for_testing/0, start_link/1, init/1]).

start() -> 
    spawn(fun() -> supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, _Arg=[]) end).
start_in_shell_for_testing() -> 
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, _Arg=[]),
    unlink(Pid).

start_link(Args) -> 
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Args).

init([]) ->
    gen_event:swap_handler(alarm_handler, {alarm_handler, swap}, {my_alarm_handler, xyz}),
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 3, 10},
         [{tag1, 
            {area_server, start_link, []},
            permanent, 
            10000, 
            worker, 
            [area_server]},
          {tag2, 
            {prime_server, start_link, []},
            permanent, 
            10000, 
            worker, 
            [prime_server]}
        ]}}.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
{'EXIT',
                 {undef,
                     [{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]],[]},
```

is saying that there is an `undef` error, namely that in the module `sellaprime_app` there is no function defined called `start()`, which takes the two arguments: `[normal, []]`.  But, if you look at your `sellaprime_app.erl`, there is clearly a function named `start()` and it's defined to take any two arguments.  So what's going on?

The problem is that the book doesn't instruct you to compile the file `sellaprime_app.erl` to create the required `.beam` file, so erlang can't find the functions therein. You will have the same problem with all the other source files. You can use the command line to compile all the `.erl` files in a directory, like this:

```
$ erlc *.erl
```

After you do that, you will see the `.beam` files in the directory.  Then you can do:

```
$ erl -boot start_sasl -config elog3
```

...followed by the rest of the commands shown in the book.

Tools like `rebar3` take care of doing all the compiling for you and organizing the `.beam` files into other directories and adding their paths, but that doesn't happen when you are running applications by hand.